# redis hashes versus strings memory costs

Tags: redis

I've done some experiments, and it seems that redis hashes are almost always more space-efficient than strings, even when hashes contain a single field!

```
import redis
rc = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1',port=1234)

rc.flushdb()
pipe = rc.pipeline()
for i in range(1000000):
    pipe.set('stream:'+str(i)+':target',True)
f = pipe.execute()    
# uses 236 MB

rc.flushdb()
pipe = rc.pipeline()
for i in range(1000000):
    pipe.hset('stream:'+str(i),'target',True)
f = pipe.execute()
# uses 170 MB

rc.flushdb()
pipe = rc.pipeline()
for i in range(500000):
    pipe.set('stream:'+str(i)+':target',True)
    pipe.set('stream:'+str(i)+':ws',True)
f = pipe.execute()
# uses 238 MB

rc.flushdb()
pipe = rc.pipeline()
for i in range(500000):
    pipe.hset('stream:'+str(i),':target',True)
    pipe.hset('stream:'+str(i),':ws',True)
f = pipe.execute()
# uses 113 MB
```

Both hashes and strings have O(1) amortized write/read costs. If I don't need to use the most fancy operations like APPEND, GETBIT, SETBIT, RANGE, etc. and use it only purely SET/GET semantics, then wouldn't a hash always be more preferable? Is there something crazy I'm missing? Also, I would love to know why hashes are so much more space efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Memory Optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization) article discusses some of the issues you've raised.

The recommendation from redis is to use hashes if you can represent your data as such. "Small hashes are encoded in a very small space, so you should try representing your data using hashes every time it is possible".

Hashes are considered small by redis if redis can pack the hash into an array and still query at an O(1), amortized. Having data in a contiguous memory region also helps with performance, especially if the adjacent elements of the array are read within the frame of the cache line on your box.

In the redis config you can find the following settings,

```
# Hashes are encoded using a memory efficient data structure when they have a
# small number of entries, and the biggest entry does not exceed a given
# threshold. These thresholds can be configured using the following directives.
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
```

You'll want to repeat your tests on both sides of the thresholds above. Overall it is best to have your tests mimicking your real data and access patterns as close as possible. The premise of your question is that hashes should always be used, but remember that you are counting on optimisation heuristics which aren't fully transparent to you as a user.

Comment: Can you clarify the "they" in "if they are are small"? The hash key? The hash field? The corresponding value?

Comment: ps the optimizations page mainly describes optimizations when keys are split into integer component fields (which isn't really the case here)

Comment: @proteneer I've expanded the discussion in the answer.